# Coronasdk Issue with addeventListeners

Tags: lua, coronasdk

recently I was coding a new game when I ran across a problem of which I cannot seem to be able to fix.

This is the code :

```
    function newPower() 
rand = math.random( 100 )

if (rand < 80) then
    powerup = display.newImage("power.png");
    powerup.class = "powerup"
    powerup.x = 60 + math.random( 160 )
    powerup.y = -100
    physics.addBody( powerup, { density=0.9, friction=0.3, bounce=0.3} )
    powerup:addEventListener( "touch", handlePowerTouch )
    end
    end
    local function handlePowerTouch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
    currentScore = currentScore * 2
    currentScoreDisplay.text = string.format( "%06d", currentScore )
    event.target:removeSelf()
    return true
    end
    end
    local function spawnpowers()
    -- Spawn a new powerup every second until canceled.
    spawnPower = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, newPower, -1 )
    end
```

Any help fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated! 
The issue I'm having is when I click "run" or "play" the game starts working then crashes and displays this message:

addEventListener: listener cannot be nil: nil stack traceback:
?: in function 'addeventListener'
game.lua63: in function'_listener'   <-- i have given you game.lua:63 above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
powerup:addEventListener( "touch", handlePowerTouch )
```

Here handlePowerTouch is nil as the function definition follows after this line.

Move your function definition in front of that line, then it should work.

Btw, is there any reason why you have so many global variables? You should use local variables wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks so much, I Have been trying to fix that for 2 days now, No there isn't any reason for all the global variables, I Just fixed that. The only Global Variable I needed was the "HandlePowerTouch" one. Thank you for your help. I'm quite new to corona so thanks for lending me a hand.

Comment: local would also be fine for handlePowerTouch as long as you only have to use it within your newPower scope. Only make sure it is defined befor you have to use it.
The error message told you what's wrong. You just have to find out why something is nil and fix it. pretty straight forward.